# How to get tesseract-ocr to recognize charters from the IPA alphabet?

Tags: macos, tesseract

I tried the following command with the image bellow:

```
$ tesseract image.png output tessedit_char_whitelist=ʌəɑɪʊɔæɜʒʃʧθŋʤð
```

[image]

The output is:

```
read_params_file: Can't open tessedit_char_whitelist=ʌəɑɪʊɔæɜʒʃʧθŋʤð
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v3.05.01 with Leptonica
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
```

Also tried passing the file list.txt with the same IPA characters

```
read_params_file: Can't open tessedit_char_whitelist=list.txt
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v3.05.01 with Leptonica
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
```

Comment: tessedit_char_whitelist won't do what you want because you can list only characters that are already known to Tesseract in the language you are scanning.  The point of tessedit_char_whitelist is to limit Tesseract to a fixed selection of characters from the ones it already knows about, not to add new characters that weren't in the language. For the latter, you'll need to add a new language with the -l option, and if there isn't already a language containing the characters you want, you might need to train one, see https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Training-Tesseract

Comment: @SilasS.Brown I didn't want to download the word definitions from some online dictionary, that's why I wanted Tesseract to recognize the IPA characters in the definitions I already had.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might not directly provide an answer to your question but hope to give some information to move on.

For tesseract to OCR IPA symbols, it needs to have the `trained data` file of that language, eg. `ipa.traineddata`. (See current language data file available [here](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Data-Files#data-files-for-version-400-november-29-2016).)

If you do have the IPA trained data file prepared yourself, use the `-l LANG[+LANG]` language option to specific in the command line. For config variables, need to specific as `-c VAR=VALUE`.

The following are the sample command lines. The first one specified to use IPA with a whitelist. The second one just uses IPA to detect as much as possible for all the IPA symbols in the `ipa.traineddata` data file.

`$ tesseract image.png output -l ipa -c tessedit_char_whitelist=ʌəɑɪʊɔæɜʒʃʧθŋʤð`

`$ tesseract image.png output -l ipa`

If you plan to build and train your own IPA data file, you may check [Data File](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Data-Files#data-files-for-version-400-november-29-2016) and [Training-Tesseract-3.00-3.02](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Training-Tesseract-3.00%E2%80%933.02).